# How can I disable logging in a gem that extends HTTParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, logging, httparty

Is it possible to disable logging to `debug_output`? Or do I have to override a method for a class after I instantiate it? Or something else?

Using the [mws gem](https://github.com/elyngved/ruby-mws/blob/master/lib/ruby-mws/api/base.rb#L10) I see that it extends HTTParty and sets `debug_output` to `$stderr`:

[image]

In the HTTParty gem I see it [has a place for using default options](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb#L209) with `debug_output`:

[image]

If I am using the mws gem, which is building a module and class wrapper for HTTParty, how can I override the setting so that my development log isn't filled up by the contents of the `debug_output` call ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesnt look like the ruby-mws gem has an API for this, but you should be able to override this in an initializer. Give this a try:

```
# config/initializers/ruby_mws.rb
class MWS::API::Base
  debug_output nil
end
```

If you only want this in development you can wrap the code with `if Rails.env == 'development'`

Comment: No, you're simply calling the method, not redefining it

Answer (score 1):

In development.rb :

```
MWS::API::Base.debug_output(nil)
```